# Persisting Order AggregateRoot Without Using ORM

Tags: c#, repository, persistence, aggregateroot

I have an aggregate root Order with its child aggregates OrderLine, i am trying to implement repository pattern without using ORM frameworks, only ADO.Net, and to say the truth my brain stack is a bit overflowed.

One way that i learned was to use [Projac](https://github.com/yreynhout/Projac), its idea is to record events inside aggregate root and than use them to save changes to database. Now i am trying to avoid using *Projac* with *events* and want to implement repository which will detect changes inside AggregateRoot and save them to database. Is there any best practice to do it without using ORM? I really couldn't find anything, all example that i have seen are using EF or Nhibernate, or other ORMs.

Thank you.

**Order Aggregate Root:**

```
    // Skipped most of properties
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; private set; }
    public bool IsFinalized { get; private set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; private set; }

    public void FinalizeOrder()
    {
        IsFinalized = true;
    }

    public void AddOrderLine(int stockItemID)
    {
        var orderLine = new OrderLine(0, OrderID, stockItemID);
        OrderLines.Add(orderLine);
    }
}
```

**OrderLine Aggregate:**

```
    // Skipped most of properties
public class OrderLine
{
    public OrderLine(int orderLineID, int orderID, int stockItemID)
    {
        OrderLineID = orderLineID;
        OrderID = orderID;
        StockItemID = stockItemID;
    }

    public int OrderLineID { get; private set; }
    public int OrderID { get; private set; }
    public int StockItemID { get; private set; }
}
```

**OrderCommanHandler and Commands:**

```
    public class OrderCommandsHandler :
    ICommandHandler<FinalizeOrderCommand>,
    ICommandHandler<AddOrderLineCommand>
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    public OrderCommandsHandler(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(AddOrderLineCommand command)
    {
        var order = orderRepository.FindByID(command.OrderID);
        order.AddOrderLine(command.StockItemID);
        orderRepository.Save(order);
    }

    public void Handle(FinalizeOrderCommand command)
    {
        var order = orderRepository.FindByID(command.OrderID);
        order.FinalizeOrder();
        orderRepository.Save(order);
    }
}

public class AddOrderLineCommand : ICommand
{
    public AddOrderLineCommand(int orderID, int stockItemID)
    {
        OrderID = orderID;
        StockItemID = stockItemID;
    }

    public int OrderID { get; private set; }
    public int StockItemID { get; private set; }
}

public class FinalizeOrderCommand : ICommand
{
    public FinalizeOrderCommand(int orderID)
    {
        OrderID = orderID;
    }

    public int OrderID { get; private set; }
}
```

**And OrderRepository:**

```
    public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public Order FindByID(int id)
    {
        // This is simple
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Save(Order order)
    {
        // Help me implement
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "child aggregates".

Comment: correct than and remove word child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any best practice to do it without using ORM? I really couldn't find anything, all example that i have seen are using EF or Nhibernate, or other ORMs.

This is really nothing to do with CQRS, Aggregates or Domain Driven Design. It's just "how do I save an object to a database". I'd recommend looking into micro-ORMs such as PetaPoco or Dapper. These give you a very lightweight abstraction to work with and have plenty of examples of how to save an object to a database. They're kinda a halfway house between working with ADO.net and a full-blown ORM such as nHibernate or EntityFramework.

Comment: Got it, but i really don't want to use ORM, i just want to know how to do it in correct way with ado.net when i will have to. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to use a micro ORM?

Comment: I know how to use them in practice, but i don't know how to do such persistence without them. It's not about "I don\t want to use ORM", its about "I want also know how to do it without them".

Comment: I'm confused - can you not just google ADO.net or even have a look at the petapoco source code - it's only 1 file and uses ADO.net. ?

Comment: I.e. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/save-delete-search-and-update-record-in-ado-net/

Comment: I'll try to explain, Let's say i have Order with 2 OrderLines in db, i retreived it from db maped to Domain object, Added one more OrderLine, Finalized it sent it to Repository and called Save. How should look Save method to be able to detect changes between database model and model to save, than generate Update query that will update Order (IsFInalized = true) and Add new OrderLine (third one) to OrderLines table. I am not good in english sorry. Got it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120660/discussion-between-quietnan-and-tomliversidge).

Comment: Ok I get it, you want to build change tracking in. Not really my area of expertise - I'd suggest you create a new question 'how do I write an ORM' or something to that effect, or read the source code for the existing ORMs as they all do this